# Proof that a Unit Root process is Difference Stationary

Tags: time-series, stationary

Consider $$y_t =a_1 y_{t-1}+a_2 y_{t-2} +...+a_p y_{t-p} +\varepsilon_t $$

The characteristic polynomial would be: $$(1-a_1L -a_2L^2 -...-a_pL^p) $$

Suppose that there is a unit root, say that $L=1$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial. Suppose this is a root of multiplicity 1 and all other roots are greater than 1 in absolute value. I am aware of the concept that $\Delta y_t$ is weakly stationary, but I have not seen a proof for this. I am looking for a proof.

Comment: How can L be 1 that’s the lag operator no?

Comment: L is the lag operator. That is correct. I am talking about the characteristic polynomial in which case we consider L a variable to consider the roots of that polynomial.

Comment: I thought in that case we are supposed to introduce new variable like let’s say lambda but in any case as long as other people won’t be confused I guess it’s fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple to see once you factorize.

In your set up there is only one unit root so the characteristic polynomial can be factorized as:

\begin{align}
y_t &= a_1 y_{t-1}+a_2 y_{t-2} +...+a_p y_{t-p} +\varepsilon_t \\
(1-a_1L -a_2L^2 -...-a_pL^p)y_t &= \varepsilon_t \\
(1-L)\phi_1(L)y_t &= \varepsilon_t \\
\phi_1(L) \Delta y_t &= \varepsilon_t
\end{align}

Here, $\phi_1(L)$ is a polynomial of degree $p-1$ and as you have mentioned in your set up, it will have all the roots outside the unit circle, making $\Delta y_t$ stationary.